# Dropdown inside textbox/textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, user-interface

I am looking for something similar to friends filter in facebook. When you type '@' inside text area it shows you a list of friends to select. I have tried to search for dropdown inside  textbox, but was not able to find what I was looking for.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you are searching for

http://podio.github.io/jquery-mentions-input/

Or

https://github.com/jakiestfu/Mention.js/

Another one

http://www.emposha.com/demo/fcbkcomplete_2/

Answer (score 4):

Writing this in **2021**

Many of the suggested libraries are not actively developed/supported, and haven't been touched in many years.

There is this library called tribute which might be of good help:

Working Example: https://zurb.github.io/tribute/example/

Github Repo: https://github.com/zurb/tribute

Comment: Was just about to close this tab due to age when I spotted this answer. Nice one.

Answer (score 1):

JQueryUI might be an option here, could just be for reference.
[JQuery UI autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

Comment: yup u can use aurtocomplete but you have to change a lot in back end while getting data in keypress event

Answer (score 0):

This seems quite similar to your needs
http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Answer (score 0):

After playing with all of these options, I have to say that at.js is far and away the better option.  Both the podio library and the mentions.js library mentioned in the selected answer are hardly supported any more and full of issues.  At.js has over 4000 stars on github, is actively developed, and is just a better piece of software.

http://ichord.github.io/At.js/